# Dependency Injection in play/scala without using constructor injection

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection

After migrating from PlayFramework version 2.4 to version 2.5, I need to inject dependencies.

I'm avoiding to use `@Inject` for constructor DI as in this the caller class of the class that has `@Inject` also needs to get the same dependencies injected to call the callee's constructor. This increases code complexity.
Please suggest any other way of DI which does not involve injecting to constructor.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Add some code to express the dependencies and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MacWire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire) looks like a great tool for constructor injection. It is macro-based and thus typesafe and non invasive. The [README page](https://github.com/adamw/macwire/blob/master/README.md) has a very good documentation, definitely worth a look IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!! Its working good. Just an extended question for play 2.5 - we had to remove global settings while migration, is there some root package or application object where I can provide all the wirings needed for DI which will load at application start up and is accessible throughout all application classes and object files?